# Problems shrinking margins with fncychap and memoir class

Tags: margins, incompatibility, geometry, fncychap

Hullo all. I am typing/editing a doc using the `memoir` class and Bjornstrup fancy chapter headings. Whenever I try to adjust [shrink] the margins using the `geometry` package, 'odd' things happen: the bottom right corner of the greyed-in header which is 'behind' [for lack of a better word] the chapter number starts to disappear: bit-by-bit. Here is my attempt to reproduce a MWE:

The first is my `ruleofprayer.tex f`ile:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\input{preamble}
\begin{document}
\include{chapter1}
\end{document}
```

Then, here is my `preamble.tex` file:

```
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{changes}
\usepackage[Bjornstrup]{fncychap}
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
% % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % %
\ChNumVar{\fontsize{76}{80}\usefont{OT1}{pzc}{m}{n}\selectfont}
\ChTitleVar{\raggedleft\Huge\sffamily\bfseries}

\titleformat{\section}[display]
{\normalfont\Huge\scshape\mdseries\centering}{}{16pt}{\Large}
\titlespacing*{\section}
{0pt}{20pt}{16pt}

\titleformat{\subsection}
{\normalfont\Large\bfseries\centering}{}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}
{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1.0ex minus 0.2ex}{1.5ex plus 0.2ex}

\titleformat{\subsubsection}
{\normalfont\large\scshape\mdseries\centering}{}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}
{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}

\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{*2}{*2}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{*2}{*2}
% % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % 
\geometry{
  left=2.85cm,
  right=2.85cm,
  top=1.95cm,
  bottom=2.25cm
}
% % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % 
\newpagestyle{main}{
\headrule
\sethead[\scshape\chaptertitle][][]{}{}{\slshape\chaptertitle}
\setfoot[][\thepage][]{}{\thepage}{}
}
\pagestyle{main}
```

And finally a brief portion of `chapter1.tex`:

```
\chapter{Saturday Evening Prayers}
Towards evening, we stand before the holy icons (having lit a candle and   maybe some incense), with reverence and fear of God; we gather our thoughts, make the Sign of the Cross, and say:

In the Name of the Father, and of the Son, and of the Holy Spirit. Amen.

\begin{framed}
From St. Thomas Sunday until Ascension, instead of \textbf{O God, cleanse me, a sinner \ldots we say:}
Christ is risen from the dead, trampling down death by death, and upon those in the tombs bestowing life.
\end{framed}

Afterwards, we collect our thoughts, and make seven prostrations (or metanoias), saying:

\section*{The Seven--Bow Beginning}
```

If I leave the `geometry` package alone (i.e. without any values assigned to it) the greyed-in background turns out as a nice rectangle as it should; only when I attempt to 'meddle' with the geometry and mess with the margins do I encounter the problem. Thanks!

I apologize for not properly splitting the files up before. I hope this clarifies the MWE.

Comment: Can you please correct the MWE, since it's not compilable as it stands?

Comment: Put the settings for `geometry` just after the package is loaded, so that the other packages are aware of the changes it makes. Don't use `fncychap`: just the fact that the chapter issues an overfull `\hbox` message no matter the settings is a clear indication that the package is buggy.

Comment: If I add the settings for geometry after the package loads, then delete the fncychap - How do I obtain the desired chapter heading styles? Also, when I do that I get an error at the line that reads:                     \ChNumVar{\fontsize{76}{80}\usefont{OT1}{pzc}{m}{n}\selectfont}

Comment: There are many chapter heading styles available in the documentation of `memoir`. The `\ChNumVar` and `\ChTitleVar` commands are specific of fncychap.

Comment: Please forgive my ignorance here, but I just tried to use the {\jenor} chapterstyle, and I keep getting an undefined control sequence. I am not sure how to proceed, and (again forgive my lack of knowledge or remembering) I cannot remember how to include some of that code here. Thanks so much!

Comment: I doubt the chapter style is `\jenor` instead of `jenor`: try using `\chapterstyle{jenor}`.

Comment: I actually meant that I was using *\chapterstyle{jenor}* sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2):

You have an ordering problem: you are changing the margins after loading `fncychap`, which messes up its calculations. Reordering to

```
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
  left=2.85cm,
  right=2.85cm,
  top=1.95cm,
  bottom=2.25cm
}
\usepackage[Bjornstrup]{fncychap}
```

fixes the issue.